# Solve continuous function: $f(bx)-f(by)=f(x)-f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Solve for continuous function $f$ where $f(bx)-f(by)=f(x)-f(y)$ for all positive number $b$. $f$ is defined on positive numbers.

**Example**: $f(x)=\log x$

**Check**: $f(bx)-f(by)=\log x+\log b-\log b-\log y$ (verified).

**My try**: first consider the case $f(1)=0$. Since $f(bx)-f(by)=f(x)-f(y)$, then $f(xy)-f(y)=f(x)-f(1)$

Then $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$

Let $g(x)=f(e^x)$

Then $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ this is the Cauchy equation. Therefore $g$ is linear and $f$ is logarithm.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Hint: $f(x) - f(bx) = f(y) - f(by)$. L.h.s. doesn't depend on $y$, R.h.s. doesn't depend on $x$. Hence  $f(x) - f(bx) = f(y) - f(by)$ is equivalent to  $f(x) - f(bx) = const$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. The const does not depend on $x$. So it only depends on $b$. Can we say const=$h(b)$?

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike For all $b$

Comment: What domain is this defined over?  If it includes $0$, then setting $y$ to $0$ gives us $f(bx)=f(x)$ for all $b$, so $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Question seems to be wrong. Let $b=0$ , we get $f(x)=CONSTANT$ : Even the $\log$ will not work when $b=0$. Question is missing a lot of "Obvious" Conditions !

Comment: @Prem Apology. Adding missing conditions.

Comment: @JonathanZonstrike Setting $x=1$, does it mean that $f(b)=f(1)-h(b)$ so $h(b)=f(1)-f(b)$. And we get $f(bx)=f(x)+f(b)+f(1)$ which is what in "my try"

Comment: @HighGPA Yes. And you were on the right track. You almost wrote a solution. The full solution is below - note that I modified my answer to make it more short.

Comment: @HighGPA, actually $f(bx)=f(x)+f(b)\color{red}{\mathbf{-}}f(1)$.

Comment: @HighGPA - I smells like you might have gotten it right, by getting $f$ to satisfy what is more-or-less the defining functional equation of $\log()$, but I confess that it's all so messy that I can't be sure. Hopefully someone does a clean version of everything we've done in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: $f(x) = A \ln x + B$.

Proof.

Case $f(1) = 0$ is already done by High GPA in post. If $f(1) \ne 0$, consider $F(x) = f(x) - f(1)$. Hence $F(bx) - F(by) = F(x) - F(y)$ and we get the case with $F(1)=0$. As it was already proved, $F(x) = const * \ln x$. Hence $f(x) = F(x) + f(1) = A \ln x + B$. We showed that $f(x) = A \ln x + B$. It's a necessary condition. It's obvious, that it's also sufficient. The problem is solved.

P.S. I deleted the previous long proof.

Comment: You should write “Case $f(1)=0$” instead of “Case $f(x)=0$”.

Comment: @Angelo I fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: You should also change the following part of the proof by writing $f(1)$ instead of $f(0)$ and $F(1)$ instead of $F(0)$.

Comment: @Angelo Indeed:)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I do love your old proof! The new proof relies on Cauchy's equation while the old one is self-sustained and also very short.